# How to build Caliburn in release mode

Tags: .net, silverlight, nant, caliburn

I can't make nant do a release build of Caliburn using their build.cmd. Can anyone tell me how to?

What command line parameters should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I should add a few more cmds for significant build options?

Comment: That would be very convenient! Especially for for people like me with no Nant experience. Thank you for responding to this :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit `Caliburn.build` - from the docs:

> You can edit "Caliburn.build" in your root folder to configure the build for release or a number of other options.

Comment: Ok. Setting the value to release in the child property of: <target name="config" depends="init"> does the work. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Even eaiser is to use:

```
build "-D:build.config=release"
```

Remember the double qoutes! :)